# If in a normed space $a_n$ converges to $a$, prove that $||a_n||$ converges to $||a||$

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

If in a normed space an converges to $a$, prove that $||a_n||$ converges to  $||a||$

I have seen this proof: for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists and $N$ s.t. $n>N$ implies
that the $||a_n-a||<\varepsilon$

by the reverse triangle inequality for the same $N \varepsilon > ||an-a|| > |\ ||an||-||a||\ |$

and therefore it converges.

But this is the absolute value of the difference of norms.  Don't you need the norm of the difference of norms to be less than $\varepsilon$?

As in

$||\ ||an|| - ||a||\ || < \varepsilon$

not

$|\ ||an|| - ||a||\ | < \varepsilon$

Or am I confused

Thanks!

Comment: You are confused. $||a_n|| -||a||$ is the difference of two real numbers and as such a real number. So $|.|$ is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The expressions $||a_n||$ and $||a||$ are real numbers, rather than elements of your normed vector space (unless the normed vector space is $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual absolute value, in which case $||\cdot||=|\cdot|$), so you need to look at the absolute value of the difference, rather than the norm of the difference.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that.  But as you said, R is a vector space and there are other norms besides absolute value on R.  How do we know it works for all other norms?

Comment: All norms on a finite-dimensional vector space are equivalent, so there is no reason not to use the usual absolute value.

Answer (score -1):

Let your normed space be $X$. The map $||\cdot|| : X \to \mathbb R$ is continuous. Since $a_n \to a$, $||a_n|| \to ||a||$, as the norm is continuous, and continuous functions preserve sequential convergence, limits being sent to limits.

Comment: Who is the moron who puts the downvote?

Answer (score -1):

From the definition of norm, it is easily deduced that 
$$|\space\|x\|-\|y\|\space|\le \|x-y\|$$ which means that the function $f(x)= \|x\|$ of the normed space $X$ in the field of scalars $K$ (where $K=\Bbb R$ or $K=\Bbb C$) is continuous (it is uniformly continuous indeed).Thus $$a_n\to a\Rightarrow \|a_n\|\to \|a\|$$

Comment: You are a stupid Mr. downvote.